# Using existed SQLite database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

My problem is in using the existed sqlite-database in my android application.
To manage it, I used the well-known article, that describes my task - http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications

While this app starts, I'm getting the error:

```
08-17 06:35:18.416: ERROR/Database(286): sqlite3_open_v2("data/data/com.jeston.existed.sqlite/databases/android_test_db.db", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
08-17 06:35:18.437: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-17 06:35:18.457: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
```

I suspect that I use wrong path to mydatabase.I put down my android_test_db file to assets folder and, as written in the blog, gave the

```
private final static String DB_PATH = "data/data/com.jeston.existed.sqlite/databases/";
private final static String DB_NAME = "android_test_db.db";
```

So, my question is these pathes are correct or no? or may be, i'm on the wrong way in common?

thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

The db name extension has to be exactly the same as it is.
Moreover, I think your main problem is that you specify the wrong package. It has to be the root package. Try that:

```
private final static String DB_PATH = "data/data/com.jeston.existed/databases/";
```

Comment: Seems to be, no - becouse of after this change I've got the mistake:  unable to open database file. in experience way, i've localized the error in my method:

    public int getCountRecords()
     {
Cursor c = myDB.query(DB_NAME, new String[] {"_id","name","age"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    return c.getCount();
    };
this method throws the exception - no such table "android_test_table"

Comment: oh right, but why do you query on DB_NAME? The first parameter of query(...) has to be the table name.

Comment: Yeeeh, your right, absolutely.Thanks, problem was in that my first argument was database's name and not table's name.

Answer (score 0):

the openDataBase method should look like this:

```
 public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
}
```

use `SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS` instead of `SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY`